# confirmed parent tranaction, but electrum used same address

Tags: electrum

I send a btc that its parent transaction was confirmed, but still electrum used the address used for receiving that fund, why? (there was some sending out unconfirmed transactions in my wallet but obviously those are irrelevant)

Comment: Did you use the Child Pays For Parent feature?

Comment: As I said all incoming transactions were confirmed the reason I mention unconfirmed outgoing transactions was because of though may be electrum have a bug that still use old address when unconfirmed transactions is in the wallet even if those are irrelevant and outgoing (not incoming)

Comment: I don't comprehend your question and comment. Could you please fix the grammar and be more explicit about which address was used for what?

Comment: Now, I waited to all transactions be confirmed but again it still uses same address that received Bitcoin for sending it.

Comment: can you perhaps add screenshots that show the addresses or something? I don't understand what your problem is.

Comment: http://i64.tinypic.com/16j58nm.jpg
http://i65.tinypic.com/20b0r4z.png
the "1LZbNBHnuqy..." is electrum address as you can see both send and receive is done from same address

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't such a thing as a "sending address" in the most literal sense.

What happens is this: a transaction defines one or several recipients and what amount of bitcoins they each get. The recipients are specified through the use of the address, in this case obviously your address as you received the first payment. Now, when you spend the coins that you received in the first payment, this *transaction output* must be referenced to define which coins you're spending. To prove that you're allowed to spend them, you have to sign the transaction using the private key corresponding to the address that they were sent to in the first place. So, in the second transaction, everyone knows which address previously received the coins, so block explorer list this previous address as a "sending address". If you spend several coins, you would then obviously also see several "sending addresses".

Comment: So what is "use change addresses" option do? the "1LZbNBHnuqyczgyU2" address is directly the address I was wanting to send BTC to it from electrum

Comment: And the recipient can see electrum address (sender address)